# Simple counter jsx component

Tags: javascript, react.js, jsx

This is my first ES6 & JSX React Component. It's just a simple counter with disabling/enabling buttons on certain conditions with notice.

I would like to know if this code is OK or if you could've done something another way. I want to avoid bad practices right from the beginning.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Counter extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: 0,
    };

    this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
  }

  decrement() {
    this.setState({
      number: this.state.number - 1
    })
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState({
      number: this.state.number + 1
    })
  }

  disableIncrement() {
    if(this.state.number >= 10) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  disableDecrement() {
    if(this.state.number <= 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  notice() {
    if(this.disableIncrement()) {
      return 'You\'ve reached N° 10.';
    }
    if(this.disableDecrement()) {
      return 'You can\'t decrement. You\'re at N° 0';
    }
    return 'You can do both.';
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.number}</p>
        <button disabled={this.disableIncrement()} onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button disabled={this.disableDecrement()} onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
        <p>{this.notice()}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: it's ok, but usually things gets pretty complicated once you're dealing with multiple components; thus usually people handling the state between components using redux, relay, perhaps flux .. check it out

Comment: I know, I want to use redux and other things, but I'd like to learn at least basic react before going into another stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Krisztian Balla's answer, you can use `prevState` to set your state as React state is updated in batches.

```
this.setState({
  number: this.state.number - 1
})
```

This should be changed to:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  number: prevState.number - 1
}));
```

For more info on prevState see the first answer here.
[lifecycle event state and prevState in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806802/lifecycle-event-state-and-prevstate-in-react-js)

Comment: Thanks, my code looks simpler, but I should use the prevState because the possibility of asynchronous updates, right?

Comment: Yes. asynchronous updates can cause your program to not behave as expected.

Comment: Yes. `setState` is async and `this.state.someProperty` inside it is not the reliable source of truth

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to bind this to the notice function as well

this:

```
if(this.state.number <= 0) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Can be written as:

```
this.state.number <= 0
```

as It will return those booleans anyway

in which case you could write:

```
notice() {
  const { number } = this.state

  if(number >= 10) {
    return 'You\'ve reached N° 10.';
  }

  if(number <= 0) {
    return 'You can\'t decrement. You\'re at N° 0';
  }

  return 'You can do both.';
}
```

Note the destructuring pattern:

```
const { number } = this.state
// is the same as
const number = this.state.number
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd like to ask something:

First, you need to bind this to the notice function as well

Please explain why. It works even without `this.notice = this.notice.bind(this)` in constructor. I thought I have to bind only functions that handle events. And second question. The disableIncrement/Decrement methods return the right boolean when i shorthanded them. But the buttons wont get disabled in the render function. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I ended up with this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fae8ad746e6c9c5ec43cac30749e407b  What do you think?